# Get all documents in Firebase collection - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a list of all documents contained in my main root collection.

I have data like this:

```
collection -> doc -> collection -> doc
```

[image]
Apologies if posts - posts is confusing!

And this is the data at root level:
[image]
I was thinking something like this would work:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    return db.collection('posts').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const postData = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => postData.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
      setPosts(postData);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(posts);
```

but this just logs an empty array when it should be an array of 2 objects.

Can anyone shine some light on where i'm going wrong? And if i will be able to access the nested data from doing this?

Comment: can you show a screen shot of your database? Note that Firestore queries are shallow.

Comment: Sure, just added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update after your comment and the screenshot addition

We can see that the documents in the parent `posts` collection are displayed **with an italic font** in the Firebase console: this is because these documents are only present (in the console) as "container" of one or more sub-collection but they are not "genuine" documents.

As matter of fact, if you create a document directly under a `col1` collection with the full path `doc1/subCol1/subDoc1`, no intermediate documents will be created (i.e. no `doc1` document).

The Firebase console shows this kind of "container" (or "placeholder") in italics in order to "materialize" the hierarchy and allow you to navigate to the `subDoc1` document but `doc1` document **doesn't exist in the Firestore database**.

Let's take an example: Imagine a `doc1` document under the `col1` collection

```
col1/doc1/
```

and another one `subDoc1` under the `subCol1` (sub-)collection

```
col1/doc1/subCol1/subDoc1
```

Actually, from a technical perspective, they are not at all relating to each other. They just share a part of their path but nothing else. One side effect of this is that if you delete a document, its sub-collection(s) still exist.

So, it is normal that you get an empty array when doing `db.collection('posts').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {...})`, because you are listening to un-existing documents.

---

What you could do is to listen for the documents in one of the `posts` subcollection, as follows:

`db.collection('posts').doc('frlGy...').collection('posts').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {...});`

Another possibility would be to use a [Collection Group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#collection-group-query), to get all the elements in ALL the `posts` subcollections. But in this case you cannot have the parent and subcollections sharing the same name (i.e. `posts`).

---

### Update following your second comment

> Will I need to do it differently if I, for example, want to be able to
>   log all posts from all Users, as the Users documents technically wont
>   exist?

It all depends if you have some `user` documents or not, which is not clear.

If you do, for each of those `user` documents, create a `posts` subcollection, and use `db.collection('Users').doc(user.uid).collection('posts').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {...});`

You can also use a Collection Group query to query across the different `posts` subcollections.

If you don't have `user` documents, you can have a global `posts` collection (root collection) and you save the user `uid` as a field of each `post` document. This way you can secure them (with Security rules) and also query all posts by user. You can also easily query posts across all users.

---

You need to put the `console.log` within the callback, as follows:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    return db.collection('posts').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const postData = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => postData.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
      console.log(postData);  // <------
      setPosts(postData);
    });
  }, []);
```

---

Also note that this will only return the `frlGy...` document, not the one in the subcollection: as said above, Firestore queries are shallow. If you want to query the subcollection, you need to execute an additional query.

Comment: Thanks Renaud, but it's still only logging an empty array. I have added an image to display the data at root level.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation! Apologies, Im new to firebase so still getting used to it. 

So if I am trying to set up a data structure like: Users -> docs - >posts -> docs, i shouldn't do: db.collection('Users').doc(user.uid).collection('posts').add();?

Comment: In this case yes you can very well do that: and `db.collection('Users').doc(user.uid).collection('posts').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {...});`will work perfectly

Comment: But will that not just create an italic container document? Will I need to do it differently if I, for example, want to be able to log all posts from all Users, as the Users documents technically wont exist?

Answer (score 0):

```
   const getMarkers= async ()=> { 
        await db.collection('movies').get()
          .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            setlist(doc.data().title);
          });
        });
      }
```

Its so simple just add async and await on a function and call the function in **useeffect**